# I would like to use html code as background. How can I do that?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Hi I'm new in html and I'm wondering is it any option to html code as background in my website.  Thanks for all replyies.

Comment: probably easiest to make screen shots of viewsource or an IDE. You can use canvas to drawText and feed it the pages actual code (heh, cool), but that's a bit of work for the result.

Answer (score 0):

To add a matrix style background in HTML you can make your css property like this:

```
body{
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx8MT.gif');
    background-size: cover;
    
    
    
    height: 100vh;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i dont think, that you understood me well. I wanna use html code as background. My code makes matrix effect and I want this as background. @rom

Comment: Sorry I now understand. Just get a gif of matrix code and make that like the code like above. I changed my answer